# Common table expressions and memory usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm using a common table expression to perform some updates within a batch statement.

Is it recommended to DROP the table after I'm done with it within the loop and re-declare it on the next pass? I am deploying this script to a fairly unknown environment, am concerned about resource utilization and would like to keep memory usage to a minimum.

Edited to include source (this is within a while loop):

```
WITH UpdatedRecords AS (
    SELECT TOP 50000
           unique_id,
           is_processed
    FROM
          _TempSnapshots
    WHERE
          is_processed = 0
    ORDER BY
          unique_id DESC
)
UPDATE UpdatedRecords 
   SET is_processed = 1
```

Comment: You can't drop a derived table it is just a sub query. Are you talking about `#temporary` tables or `@table_variables`? Please show some code.

Comment: @MartinSmith sorry. Of course you're right. I just missed the "sql-server" tag.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect what I'm doing - sorry if I named it incorrectly.

Comment: Following the edit that is a common table expression. It is basically like a derived table though and you can't drop it as it doesn't exist as a table in its own right. It doesn't get materialized into a temporary table up front it just gets inlined into the query that references it.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thanks for the update. Do you have any input about the performance of this approach?

Comment: Why are you batching into `TOP 50000`? If you want to avoid lock escalation and blocking other queries `TOP 5000` may be better. If this is to avoid growing the log what recovery model is your DB in?  Apart from that difficult to say much about performance without knowing what indexes you have on your table and your data. If you have an index on `is_processed,unique_id` then locating the rows to delete will be easy. If you only have an index on `unique_id` then later iterations will take longer.

Comment: For clarity I removed the reference to "derived table" because the example *only* contains a common table expression and no derived table.

Comment: How many rows do you want to update?  Breaking it up is not a memory thing - it is a log file thing.  And is seems like is_processed = 1 would go with some other stuff.   Maybe post the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered by @MartinSmith in the comments on the question:

Following the edit that is a common table expression. It is basically like a derived table though and you can't drop it as it doesn't exist as a table in its own right. It doesn't get materialized into a temporary table up front it just gets inlined into the query that references it